# How to set up a Server 2016 VM as if it's in Australia

Tags: virtual-machines, windows-server-2016

To help troubleshoot some issues (mainly around database collation and time zone conversions), we need a VM that think's it's located in Australia. The primary goal is to have Latin1_General_CI_AS be the default collation, and for it to be in Australian Central Standard Time.

On this initial screen, is this right?

[image]

For Language, `English (United States)` is the only option.

For Time and Currency format, there is a clear winner.

For Keyboard or input method, `United Kingdom Extended` is the option that seems to make the most sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to collation this is something that most frequently comes into play with SQL Server and SQL Server databases - as it has direct impact on the way you store your text data and the way search across text works. During SQL Server setup you can select among large list of different collations which can be prefixed with "SQL_" prefix and not. First considered to be SQL Server collations, second "Windows" collations - as far as I know the latter collations are more frequently updated and more widely compatible (at least this is what I heard).

If you perform SQL Server installation in "next-next-OK" mode it will inherit default instance collation based on your Windows regional settings.

So just make it clear what exactly you trying to troubleshoot/reproduce. If it is something that not involves SQL Server, then fire off intl.cpl on affected box take a note of all settings on all tabs (don't forgot clicking on additional settings buttons and taking screenshots) and set them the same on your VM. Also keep in mind that sometime it makes sense if you have matching translated UI/language pack and additional keyboard layouts set exactly the same as on affected machine.

If this involves SQL Server, you can change collation post install as [described here](http://www.mikerodionov.com/2016/04/changing-sql-collation-for-deployed-instance/) or during install as shown below:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter. This is setup. Like the language for the SETUP - once you acutally install windows, it will ask again.

And guess what, once it is installed you can CHANGE IT ;)